# typescript: Array of templated interface extending multiple types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a minimal example of my problem

```
interface Dog {
  legs: number;
}

interface Person {
  arms: number;
}

type Living = Person | Dog;

interface Speaker<T extends Living> {
  speak: (living: T) => void;
};

const michel: Speaker<Person> = { speak: (person) => console.log(`I have ${person.arms} arms`) };

const speakers: Array<Speaker<Living>> = [michel];
```

It throw this error

```
Type 'Speaker<Person>' is not assignable to type 'Speaker<Living>'.
  Type 'Living' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
    Property 'harms' is missing in type 'Dog' but required in type 'Person'
```

I would like to have an array of `Speaker` that accepts any type of `Living`.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you've defined things, `Speaker<Living>` means an object with a speak function that takes in a `Person | Dog` as its argument. When you create `michel`, you have the following function, which works fine if given a `Person`:

```
(person) => console.log(`I have ${person.arms} arms`)
```

But it would not work if given a `Person | Dog`, because it's trying to access the `.arms` property of a dog. That mismatch and others is why typescript is telling you that `Speaker<Person>` cannot be assigned to `Speaker<Living>`

If you want the array to be a mix of objects, some of which take `Person`s for their speak function, some of which take `Dog`s, then the type for that will be:

```
const speakers: Array<Speaker<Person> | Speaker<Dog>> = [michel];
```

---

EDIT: if your `Living` union is large, or you want speakers to update automatically when more types are added into `Living`, then you can use the following to get typescript to generate the `Speaker<Person> | Speaker<Dog>` union for you:

```
type Distribute<T> = T extends Living ? Speaker<T> : never;

const speakers: Array<Distribute<Living>> = [michel];
// speakers is of type Array<Speaker<Person> | Speaker<Dog>>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=60&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeBYAKGWQBsJMBnALmRAFcBbAI2gG5CBfQw0SWRFAAVoFdCFyFicKA2q1GLKOwJcChMAE8ADigAywAG6hsAXmTCoo8QB80WZT3DR4SZAGUdcANbQAPABVkCAAPSBAAEwpkfSMQTAA+CSJkCk8vGgAKEkNjGn8ASmQTRIN0YHDlDgcCBDEKMGQGYAQACwgSGg8Ibz8LK0SzHBS0zJ1LMULi5FqQUTIAOhIsDIADAElkFrgDFAASHDGreelZDmQTihXCqu4CTR00YHqoYCY6SACB5ECQsMjonJxZAAfncaT8-kSNBAEB2SluM3qw26PksNAAglAoHANL5UE8wC83h8YsZ4l8ANpNVrtAC6rCAA)

Comment: Okay I got it.
Is there a way of specifying all the Living instead of putting multiple `|`?
For example if I add a new type to the `Living` I would like this array to be automatically retyped.

Comment: Added in an example of how to do that